# USA: J1 Visa Interview shortly before or after official start date -- is the a problem?

Tags: usa, student-visa

I want to enter the US on a J1 visa - I am waiting for the DS-2019 form, and I am afraid it might arrive only very shortly before my J1 start date, so that I might have my interview only just before or even after the official start date. Is this even possible? My host institution is flexible here, but what about the US embassy?